Golang YAML Unmarshal doesn't unmarshal nested yaml keys
I'd like to load a list of objects from a yaml file but for some reason the nested properties in my yaml file are not properly loaded:
This is the struct I'm trying to Unmarshal to:
type Deck struct {
    Characters []struct {
        Name             string `yaml:"name"`
        Cost             int    `yaml:"cost"`
        Health           int    `yaml:"health"`
        Attack           int    `yaml:"attack"`
        SpecialAbilities []struct {
            Name        string `yaml:"name"`
            Description string `yaml:"description"`
            Effect      string `yaml:"effect,omitempty"`
        } `yaml:"special_abilities"`
    } `yaml:"characters"`
}

This is my loading function:
func LoadDeck() *Deck {

    yamlFile, err := os.ReadFile("characters.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    deck := &Deck{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, deck)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    return deck
}

This is the characters.yaml file I'm trying to unmarshal:
characters:
  - name: "Er Cipolla"
    cost: 5
    health: 10
    attack: 2
    special_abilities:
      - name: "Battelcry"
        description: "Makes everybody cry, it inflicts 1 damage"
        effect: "Something happens"
      - name: "Shield"
        description: "This minion shields the others"
  - name: "Fagiolino"
    cost: 2
    health: 2
    attack: 3
    special_abilities:
      - name: "Shield"
        description: "This minion shields the others"
        effect: "Something happens"


This is the output, as you can see the special_abilities are empty:
&{[{Er Cipolla 5 10 2 []} {Fagiolino 2 2 3 []}]}


Maybe its because the package you are using.
I'm using
require gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0

and it works.

I'm using k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/yaml,
I tried using the latest version of yours https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/tree/v3.0.1 and it works for me too. Thanks for the support
